# Batch file PAUSE requires two key presses to dismiss

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I have the following code:

```
@echo off
set scriptTitle=Mode Changer
title %scriptTitle%



rem Take Details
set /p machine=Enter machine name:%=%
echo. %machine%
set /p rMSNewMode=Mode (t/l):%=%
echo. %rMSNewMode%

rem Perform Task
cls

rem Check machine existence
ping %machine% -n 1
if %errorLevel% == 1 call:error "The specified machine (%machine%) could not be located."


:error
color 4f
title ERROR: %scriptTitle%
cls
echo. The following error has occurred:
echo.
echo. %~1
echo.
pause
goto EOF
```

Once the batch file has completed, I get the 'Press any key to continue' as expected. However, it requires 'any key' to be pressed twice before the batch file will end. It appears if I replace the following line:

```
if %errorLevel% == 1 call:error "The specified machine (%machine%) could not be located."
```

with

```
if %errorLevel% == 1 goto error
```

I only get prompted once.

What is the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike many languages, batch has no concept of the end of a "procedure" - it simply continues execution line-by-line until it reaches the end-of-file. Consequently, you need to `goto :eof` after completing the mainline, otherwise execution will continue through the subroutine code. `:EOF` is a predefined label understood by `CMD` to mean `end of file`. The colon is **required**.

When you `call :label` batch returns at the end-of-file (because the label is `call`ed) to the statement after the `call` - which is the `color 4f` within the `error` routine. Having just executed the `pause` just before returning, batch just charges on, line-by-line, until it once again encounters the `pause` - hence two prompt/response cycles.

Comment: +1, but the colon ***is required*** with `CALL`, otherwise it will look for a batch file instead of a label within the current script. The colon is not needed when using `GOTO`, except when using the implicit `:EOF` label. I prefer to use `EXIT /B` over `GOTO :EOF`, but they are functionally equivalent.

Comment: @dbenham : Quite correct. Fixed. It's the `goto :label` where the colon is optional (and IMHO best omitted). Good spotting!